# c++ error: no matching function for call to... of my graph code

Tags: c++, graph

This code is about graph with node and edge. I am trying to add `addEdge` method for my graph class, I have difined the Edge constructor(with Node*, Node*, E), but why `no matching function` appear?

1. Can anybody help me figure this error out?
2. and "warning: address of local variable"?, I just want to return the node address, how to fix it?

```cpp
//Graph.h
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#pragma once
using namespace std;
namespace gdwg {
template <typename N, typename E>
class Graph{
public:
    Graph(){}
    Graph(N val, E w){}
    void addNode(N val){ nodes.push_back(Node(val)); }
    
    void addEdge(N src, N dst, E w){
        Node* srcptr = findNode(src);
        Node* dstptr = findNode(dst);
        Edge edge(srcptr, dstptr, w);
        srcptr->appendOutEdgeToNode(edge);
        dstptr->appendInEdgeToNode(edge);
    }
    void printNodes(){ 
        for(auto n: nodes){
            cout << n.val << endl; 
            for(auto edge: n.in_edges)
                cout << "--" << edge.w << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    struct Edge;
    struct Node{
        Node(N _val){ val = _val; }
        void appendInEdgeToNode(Edge edge){ in_edges.insert(edge); }
        void appendOutEdgeToNode(Edge edge){ out_edges.insert(edge); }
        N val;
        set<Edge> in_edges, out_edges;
    };
    struct Edge{
        Edge(Node* _src, Node* _dst, E _w){ src=_src; dst=_dst; w=_w; }
        Node* src, dst;
        E w;
    };
    vector<Node> nodes;
    
    Node* findNode(N val){
        for(auto n: nodes){
            if(n.val == val)
                return &n;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
#include "Graph.tem"
} // namespace gdwg
```

and here are reports after `g++ *.cpp -o main -g -O0 -std=c++11`:

```
Graph.h:45:12: warning: address of local variable ‘n’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   for(auto n: nodes){
            ^
Graph.h: In instantiation of ‘gdwg::Graph<N, E>::Edge::Edge(gdwg::Graph<N, E>::Node*, gdwg::Graph<N, E>::Node*, E) [with N
 = int; E = int]’:
Graph.h:17:30:   required from ‘void gdwg::Graph<N, E>::addEdge(N, N, E) [with N = int; E = int]’
test1.cpp:17:24:   required from here
Graph.h:38:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘gdwg::Graph<int, int>::Node::Node()’
   Edge(Node* _src, Node* _dst, E _w){ src=_src; dst=_dst; w=_w; }
```

Comment: Try for(auto& n: nodes) then n is reference not local variable.

Comment: cool! it works, tkx a lot!